# How to use avg()

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am very new to SQL and can't figure this out.

Where I am trying to do is to SELECT ACCOUNT_ID, CUST_ID, PRODUCT_CD, OPEN_BRANCH_ID in which the available balance is below the average available balance.

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_ID, CUST_ID, PRODUCT_CD, OPEN_BRANCH_ID
FROM Banking.Account
HAVING AVAIL_BALANCE < AVG(AVAIL_BALANCE);
```

if I put HAVING AVAIL_BALANCE < 7000; it works.

[image]

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1):

use `join`

```
select t1.ACCOUNT_ID, t1.CUST_ID, t1.PRODUCT_CD, t1.OPEN_BRANCH_ID from 
Banking.Account t1 
Inner join (
    SELECT avg(AVAIL_BALANCE) avg_bal, ACCOUNT_ID, CUST_ID
    FROM Banking.Account group by  ACCOUNT_ID, CUST_ID
) t2 on t1.ACCOUNT_ID = t2.ACCOUNT_ID and t1.CUST_ID = t2.CUST_ID
where t1.AVAIL_BALANCE < t2.avg_bal;
```

Comment: Anyway I can just use avg(Avail_Balance)?

Comment: you need to to use subquery in order to compare, either use `left join`  or `in`